# When creating new objects, my counter stays the same number

Tags: java, object

I working on a program where I need to count the how many objects are created by a certain class (and all its sub-classes). I made a quick test program that replicated my problem:

```
public class Test {

   private int number = 0;

   public Test(){
       number++;
   }

   public int returnNumber(){
       return number;
   }
}
```

How do I make the variable 'number' save its value, instead of initializing every time I create a new object?

Comment: private int number = 0; should be private static int number = 0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `number` static in order for it to have the same value for all instances of your class.

```
private static int number = 0
```

You might want to change your `returnNumber` to be static too.

If you want each instance of your class to have a unique number, you should keep that number in a separate member :

```
public class Test {

   private int number = 0;
   private static int counter = 0;
   public Test(){
       number = counter++;
   }

   public int getNumber() {
       return number; // each instance will have a unique value
   }

   public static int getCounter () {
       return counter; // this will return the current value of the counter
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`number` needs to be a `static` type so its shared across all *instances* of your class.

Consider `private static int number = 0` instead.

Better still, you ought to make `number` an **atomic** type, so multiple constructors can be called on several threads. (Otherwise you could end up underestimating `number`.)

Consider using `AtomicInteger` as the type; still `static` of course.

Comment: std::atomic<int> => AtomicInteger ?

Comment: @Ravindrababu: oops, a momentary lapse into another language.

Answer (score 0):

create variable as static

```
   private static int number = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it

```
private static int number = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {

   private static int number = 0;

   public Test(){
       number++;
   }

   public int returnNumber(){
       return number;
   }
}
```